# Clash of Clans on wrong Google+ account when moving from iOS

Tags: ios, android, clash-of-clans

I'm having quite a problem with syncing iOS to Android...
So, I had an iPhone 4S that I was using, and I switched phones with my Dad, so I would get a Samsung S4 instead of my iPhone 4S. The thing is, I was wondering how to sync iOS to Android, so I looked it up and did it.
Here's where the problem starts.

My Dad had his Google Account logged on the Samsung when I linked the CoC account, so now it is linked to *his* account. Then, I put my own Google Account on the Samsung. Sadly, Clash of Clans only lets you synchronize to another kind of phone once, and when I tried to get the code again on my iPad (which was synced to my iPhone *via* Game Center), it wouldn't give me the code. **So now my Clash of Clans is stuck on my dad's Google account**.

How to get my account linked to my Google Play account, and not my Dad's ?

Comment: Have you contacted their support?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already used your one sync, then you are kind of stuck. When switching devices, they allow you only one sync. This is for security reasons, but it kind of acts as an inconvenience here. There is almost no way to get your account synced after that. I would recommend contacting Supercell if you are desperate.

Answer (score -1):

Well it is pretty simple if you are using iOS to Android. I'm currently using Android so I'm not fully sure if this will work. In your new phone make sure you are less than TH4 in Clash of Clans. Then, in your old device, open Clash of Clans, then goto Settings, Then click link a device, then click this is an old device, then click "I want to link to another device" and then you should get a code. Goto your Galaxy S4, and hit new device, and enter the code. Simple as that? :)